# Can't enable "Manage your WhatsApp Accounts" option in facebook embedded signup

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to integrate whatsapp embedded signup as business solution provider. I have implemented the embedded signup following their documentation. I can enable and disable the "Manage your WhatsApp Accounts" option from other 3rd party bsp. So I have created a whatsapp business account and added a whatsapp number. Here is a embedded signup flow:

[[[Embedded signup flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UXgi.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NPrH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULv7B.png)

Here is the code we followed:

`

```
$_Company_WHATSAPP_OPENAPI = {
    APP_ID: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    system_user_access_token : "token",
    getOpenAPiPage: function () {
            $_Company_WHATSAPP_OPENAPI.loadAPI();
    },

    getBtnHtml: function () {
        return '<button id="loginButtonWhatsApp" onClick="$_Company_WHATSAPP_OPENAPI.launchWhatsAppSignup()" style="background-color: #1877f2; border: 0; border-radius: 4px; color: #fff; cursor: pointer; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; height: 40px; padding: 0 24px;">Login with Facebook</button>';
    },

    loadAPI: function () {
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            // JavaScript SDK configuration and setup
            FB.init({
                appId: $_Company_WHATSAPP_OPENAPI.APP_ID, // Facebook App ID
                cookie: true, // enable cookies
                xfbml: true, // parse social plugins on this page
                version: 'v15.0' //Graph API version
            });
        };
        // Load the JavaScript SDK asynchronously
        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    },

    launchWhatsAppSignup: function () {
        function waitForFbq(callback){
            if(typeof fbq !== 'undefined'){
                callback()
            } else {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    waitForFbq(callback)
                }, 100)
            }
        }
        waitForFbq(function () {
           fbq && fbq('track', 'WhatsAppOnboardingStart', {
                appId: $_Company_WHATSAPP_OPENAPI.APP_ID,
                feature: 'whatsapp_embedded_signup'
            });
        })

        // Launch Facebook login
        FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                const accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    console.log("FB login access token : ",accessToken);
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        }, {
            scope: 'business_management,whatsapp_business_management,email,public_profile,whatsapp_business_messaging',
            extras: {
                feature: 'whatsapp_embedded_signup',
                setup: {
                    business: {
                        name: 'Some company.',
                        email: 'rupen@company.com',
                        phone: {
                            code: 1,
                            number: '6505551234'
                        },
                        website: 'https://www.company.com',
                        address: {
                            streetAddress1: '1 Acme Way',
                            city: 'Acme Town',
                            state: 'CA',
                            zipPostal: '94000',
                            country: 'BD'
                        },
                        timezone: 'UTC-08:00'
                    },
                    phone: {
                        displayName: 'Acme Inc.',
                        category: 'ENTERTAIN',
                        description: ''
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    },
}
```

`

Is there any permission that I am missing?

I have added whatsapp_business_management permission in the scope.As it is responsible for managing whatsapp accounts, I have expected that it will enable "Manage your WhatApp accounts" option.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is try creating a new app from developer.facebook.com. My thinking is after becoming solution partners we have to create a new app to see this options!! I faced this same problem for over 2 weeks. finally solved it.